# Using COALESCE function to make values separated with commas

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (`EMP`) I know that using the `COALESCE` function we can get the values of any  column in this  way

```
23,23,45,34

SELECT OfferID  FROM Emp where EmpID= 23
```

but I am not getting the syntax to achieve this

Any help would be great, to resolve this issue.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + CAST(OfferID AS VARCHAR)
FROM   Emp
WHERE  EmpID = 23

SELECT @List
```

This approach to aggregate concatenation is [not guaranteed to work](https://web.archive.org/web/20080203143315/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515). If you are on at least SQL Server 2005 `XML PATH` or CLR aggregates are preferred.

The definitive article on the subject is [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: @GertArnold - thanks. Replaced with internet archive link. I've no idea why Microsoft doesn't preserve KB articles more permanently.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nuisance sometimes. They probably delete them when the hit count equals the world population.

Answer (score 45):

#### Description

I have done this using `COALESCE` in the past too, but i suggest another approach because you dont need a variable. Use the `T-SQL` function `STUFF` to get this done.

#### Sample

```
SELECT STUFF((
    select ','+ cast(OfferID as nvarchar(255)) 
    from Emp b
    WHERE a.EmpID= b.EmpID
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS COLUMN2
FROM Emp a
GROUP BY a.EmpID
```

#### More Information

[STUFF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: +1 - I too feel this is much much better than `COALESCE`. There I was getting all the numbers in all the rows. Here I am getting all the numbers for one single unique row. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

[dknaack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8700995/1192811) has some drawbacks when text contains some XML caracters like `<`, which are html-entitized as `&lt;`. This can be solved using the [`TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) directive which sends the response as xml, then extract the raw `value` as string.

There are plenty more solutions to the problem in this article :
[Concatenating Row Values in T-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

#### Sample

```
SELECT STUFF((
    select ','+ cast(OfferID as nvarchar(255)) 
    from Emp b
    WHERE a.EmpID= b.EmpID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'') AS COLUMN2
FROM Emp a
GROUP BY a.EmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be possible in your case, but if you want to consider null value too in the select list, then you should use the below query:

```
Declare @singleRowValue varchar(8000) ;

Select @singlerowvalue = COALESCE(@singleRowValue + ',', '') + ISNULL(CAST(OfferID as varchar(30)),'null') from EMP

Select  @singleRowValue ;
```

Answer (score -2):

Isnull Function will also give us the same result

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @List = ISNULL(@List + ',', '') + CAST(OfferID AS VARCHAR)
FROM   Emp
WHERE  EmpID = 23

SELECT @List
```