# Suggest the query to fetch the required result in one query with performance

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am able to fetch the results using the temp tables or looping over this table but I want to translate the following table into the required result in one query with great performance.

```
Order Table

OrdNbr  LineNbr ItemName    Qty
1       1       Pen         1
1       2       Pencil      2
1       3       Scale       2
2       5       Bottle      2
3       3       Pen         10
3       1       Pencil      5

Required Result:

OrdNbr  OrdNbrFirstLineNbr  ItemName    Qty     AllLineNumbers
1       1-1                 Pen         1       1,2,3
2       2-5                 Bottle      2       5
3       3-1                 Pencil      5       1,3
```

OrdNbr and LineNbr are primary key for order table. I want to fetch only first record for the same OrdNbr.

Logic to get the result:
Find the distinct order number and get the lowest line number for the individual order number. Now display the order number, lowest line number and details for that lowest line number in that order. I want two extra derived fields OrdNbrFirstLineNbr and AllLineNumbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
select OrdNbr, 
       LineNbr as OrdNbrFirstLineNbr, 
       ItemName, 
       Qty
from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by OrdNbr order by LineNbr) as rn
   from "Order"  -- need to quote this, because order is a reserved word
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I want the columns OrdNbrFirstLineNbr and AllLineNumbers also.

Comment: @Romil: the "first lineNbr" is the one selected (because of the where clause. I don't know if there is an easy way to do an "aggregation of the of the line numbers in SQL Server.

Comment: We have coalesce function to do aggregation in sql server.

Comment: @Romil: colaesce is not an aggregate function. It picks the first non-null value of a list of expressions. It will not concatenate the column values from different rows (but I'd love to be proven wrong with an example)

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas

Comment: @Romil: it's not `coalesce()` that does the aggregation in that example. It's the `+` operator which concatenates everything into a variable. `coalesce()` is only used to ensure that the initial NULL values is treated as an empty string. The concatenation does not really need the coalesce(). See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10b83/3

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT OrdNbr, LineNbr, ItemName, Qty 
FROM Order
GROUP BY OrdNbr
ORDER BY LineNbr;
```

Comment: Fail. `LineNbr`, `ItemName` and `Qty` can't be returned as they are not part of the aggregate clause.

Comment: This query is not returning the expected results.