# Handling NULL value in FOR XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
            SELECT Col1
    FROM Table
    WHERE Col2 = 63895746
    ORDER BY Col
    FOR XML PATH,TYPE
```

I dont need NULLS in the result.
 i want result to be wrapped by something like 
     < Cols >< /Cols > even if col1 is null or not

In this example Table doesn't contain any rows for col2 = 63895746 , so i will get an empty result set, so the type directive will make it  NULL and return it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
;with mytmp (f1) as (
  SELECT Col1
  FROM Table
  WHERE Col1 = 123456
  ORDER BY Col1
  FOR XML PATH('col'),root('cols'),TYPE
  )
select isnull(f1, '<cols></cols>')
from mytmp;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use ELEMENTS XSINIL;

[including-null-columns-empty-elements](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/including-null-columns-empty-elements-125474.aspx)

Failing that you could nest your query:

> SELECT ISNULL(data.Col1,'< Cols >< /Cols >') AS Col1
>   FROM (
>   SELECT Col1
>       FROM Table
>       WHERE Col2 = 63895746
>       ORDER BY Col
>       FOR XML PATH,TYPE
>   ) data

Not at my machine so makes it a little tough to test.

Comment: You could also try the STUFF command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas

Comment: @Ashley John - "XSINIL" sounds like *exactly* what you want.  It *does* require at least one non-null column ... for the simple reason that if there's nothing there, no row is returned.  If you want to return *all* rows (even rows where your column of interest happens to be null), perhaps the simplest approach is to select a *second* column in your query.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T.X
FROM
  (
  SELECT Col1
  FROM Table
  WHERE Col2 = 63895746
  ORDER BY Col
  FOR XML PATH, TYPE
  ) AS T
FOR XML PATH('Cols'), TYPE
```

Comment: With little tweaks to this answer, i got what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If Col1 is a string then you can use the following to achieve this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Col1,'')
FROM Table
WHERE Col2 = 63895746
ORDER BY Col
FOR XML PATH,TYPE
```

That will give you an empty tag if you have a null value

Comment: Yep, works fine on my SQL 2012 LocalDB that I have here on my laptop, I tested it before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

i think, in according with microsoft, is use

```
ELEMENTS XSINIL
```

as option, after for xml path

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/columns-that-contain-a-null-value-by-default?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Col1, '< Cols >< /Cols>') AS Col1
FROM Table
WHERE Col2 = 63895746
ORDER BY Col
FOR XML PATH,TYPE
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Please add that too.

Comment: if COL1 is NULL then result = <Cols></Cols>