# Merge columns from three different database tables

Tags: sql

I'm addicted to this problem and tried to fix it myself, but I cannot solve it.

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. Post
2. Category
3. jo_post_cat

How do I use the SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN jo_post_cat on post.ID = jo_post_cat.j_postid 
LEFT JOIN category as ca on jo_post_cat.j_catid = ca.ca_id
```

[image]

From the picture you will see that the `ID` is not unique, but with my `ca_id` `ca_name` it is unique.  I would like to give a combined `ca_id` `ca_name` in the same row?  I would like it in this format `Num 1, Num 2`.

Comment: Possible duplication of question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas

Comment: change "select *" to "select just what you need".

Answer (score 0):

you need to show ca_id and ca_name in same row? like ca_id-ca_name if that is the case then append the two column data and display.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to appear in the same row.

The command should I use?

Comment: you can try below code
SELECT (ID + '-' + name) AS ID FROM tablename

Comment: I didn't want this to be a ca_id, ca_name.

But I want you to. The second row of data into the data row 1.
When combined, these data will be ca_id = 1, 2 = 1-num, num2 ca_name.

Comment: if possible can you post the format in which you want your resultset should come i mean the way you have attached previous image.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you what you're looking for if you're using SQL Server

```
SELECT 'Num' + ca.ca_id + ', ' + ca_name AS combinedName
FROM post 
    INNER JOIN jo_post_cat on post.ID = jo_post_cat.j_postid 
    LEFT JOIN category as ca on jo_post_cat.j_catid = ca.ca_id
```

This would return

```
combinedName
Num 1, Num 1
Num 2, Num 2
```

Comment: I tried to apply this Code to Run in the SQL, but it wasn't at all. The result is the same. The data does not include a single line to the line.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure what that means. changing your SELECT statement wouldn't affect how many rows are returned.

Comment: If this cannot be done in an SQL statement must be made in the Code?

If you used to do? How do I use the ColdFusion language.

Comment: you need to better clarify what you want. I posted SQL code that seems to solve your issue, but you haven't spelled out your issue very clearly.