# sql query with binding n columns in one column and display with comma if value present else only show null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

in this contactno is combining in 5 columns from other table but problem is when data is fetched for contact number if it has null values it only display ",(comma)" so i want to disable it plus if it has number then it should come with separation of commas

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetGuarantorPidNoAndNameByGlSlBCode      
(      
 @GlCode INT,      
 @SlCode INT,      
 @BCode INT      
)      
AS      

 DECLARE @Guarantor1 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor2 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor3 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor4 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor5 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor6 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor7 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor8 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor9 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor10 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor11 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor12 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor13 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor14 INT      
 DECLARE @Guarantor15 INT      
 DECLARE @MaxNoOfGuarantor INT      
 DECLARE @LoopCount INT      
 DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(150)      
 DECLARE @NameInMarathi NVARCHAR(150)      
 DECLARE @Address1 NVARCHAR(150)      
 DECLARE @Address2 NVARCHAR(150)      
 DECLARE @Address3 NVARCHAR(100)      
 DECLARE @ContactNo NVARCHAR(60)      

 SET @MaxNoOfGuarantor = 15      
 SET @LoopCount = 0      

 SELECT  @Guarantor1 = ISNULL(Garentor1,0), @Guarantor2 = ISNULL(Garentor2,0), @Guarantor3 = ISNULL(Garentor3,0),  @Guarantor4 = ISNULL(Garentor4,0),  @Guarantor5 = ISNULL(Garentor5,0),      
  @Guarantor6 = ISNULL(Garentor6,0),  @Guarantor7 = ISNULL(Garentor7,0), @Guarantor8 = ISNULL(Garentor8,0), @Guarantor9 = ISNULL(Garentor9,0), @Guarantor10 = ISNULL(Garentor10,0),      
  @Guarantor11 = ISNULL(Garentor11,0), @Guarantor12 = ISNULL(Garentor12,0), @Guarantor13 = ISNULL(Garentor13,0), @Guarantor14 = ISNULL(Garentor14,0), @Guarantor15 = ISNULL(Garentor15,0)      
 FROM LoanMst       
 WHERE BCode = @BCode AND GlCode = @GlCode AND SlCode = @SlCode      

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TempGuarantorInfo]') AND type in (N'U'))             
  BEGIN        
   DELETE FROM [dbo].[TempGuarantorInfo];      
  END           
  ELSE        
  BEGIN        
   CREATE TABLE dbo.TempGuarantorInfo      
   (      
    PidNo INT,      
    GuarantorName NVARCHAR(150),       
    GuarantorNameInMarathi NVARCHAR(150),      
    Address1 NVARCHAR(150),      
    Address2 NVARCHAR(150),      
    Address3 NVARCHAR(150),      
    ContactNo NVARCHAR(80)      
   )      
  END          

 IF ( @Guarantor1 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')    
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor1         

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor1, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor2 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor2        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor2, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor3 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor3        
            INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor3, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor4 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor4        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor4, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor5 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor5        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor5, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor6 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor6        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor6, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor7 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor7        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor7, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor8 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor8        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor8, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor9 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor9        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor9, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor10 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor10        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor10, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      
    IF ( @Guarantor11 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor11        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor11, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor12 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor12        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor12, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor13 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor13        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor13, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor14 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor14        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor14, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 IF ( @Guarantor15 <> 0)      
 BEGIN       

  SELECT @Name = ISNULL(CustName,''), @NameInMarathi = ISNULL(CustNameOL,'') , @Address1 = ISNULL(RAdd1OL,''), @Address2 = ISNULL(RAdd2OL,''),       
      @Address3 = ISNULL(RCityOL,'') + '-' + ISNULL(RPinOL,''), @ContactNo = ISNULL(RMobno,'') + ',' + ISNULL(PMobile,'') + ',' + ISNULL(RPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(PPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OPhone,'')+ ',' + ISNULL(OMobno,'')        
  FROM CustMst WHERE BCode = @BCode AND PidNo = @Guarantor15        

  INSERT INTO dbo.TempGuarantorInfo VALUES(@Guarantor15, @Name, @NameInMarathi, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @ContactNo)      
 END      

 SELECT * FROM dbo.TempGuarantorInfo ORDER BY PidNo
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid dumping large amounts of code without any provided context. It is unlikely that anyone is willing to go through that mess.

Comment: Ya I agree, that is an unwieldy amount of code 334

Comment: Maybe try COALESCE and use the variable `@ContactNo` like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas