# SQL Server join results as comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a company, industry, and company_industry_map many-to-many table.

```
company_id | company_name
1            Goldman Sachs
2            Microsoft

industry_id | industry
4             Technology
5             Finance
6             Banking

company_id | industry_id
1            5
1            6
2            4
```

I'd like to write a query that joins all of the industries into a comma separated list like this:

```
company_id | industries
1            Finance, Banking
2            Technology
```

Here's my general query that I'm trying to write:

```
SELECT company_id, 
       xxx AS industries 
  FROM company c, 
       company_industry_map m 
 WHERE c.company_id = m.company_id
```

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL server, MySQL, etc

Comment: You can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas

Comment: Specifically look at the answer(Rick S comment) with the highest score using the STUFF command

Comment: Please stop using the sql antipattern of implicit joins. They are a very POOR technique making it harder to maintain systems and leading to more risky  code that can contain errors such as accidnetal cross joins that explicit syntax will not allow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like this in SQL Server

```
select co.CompanyID, AllIndustries = 
       (select (cast(industry as varchar(200))+',') as [text()]
       FROM company c, 
       company_industry_map m 
       WHERE c.company_id = m.company_id and c.company_id = co.company_id 
       order by industry_id for XML PATH(''))
from Companies co
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can create a function like this:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)

set @var = ''
select @var = @var  + ',' + UserLogin from [user] 

select @var
```