# while loop to get two variables to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure to loop through the table which has membership id and person id details and pass it as variable to stored procedure.

Any thoughts on how to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
    DECLARE @membership NUMERIC(9)
DECLARE @person_id NUMERIC(9)
DECLARE @id_num INT 
WHILE (
set @id_num=id_num+1
SELECT membership_id,person_id FROM [dbo].[reb] WHERE id_num <1160


EXEC p_get_details @membership_id, person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. first one is to pass two parameters to procedure `p_get_details` , each parameter being a [**comma separated string**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas) containing concatenated values of membership_id and person_id columns.

Other is to pass the whole resultset from SELECT query as a [**Table Valued Parameter**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37174/Table-Value-Parameter-in-SQL-Server) to the procedure.

Comment: Can you tell which how I can do it with the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the proc again and again for different table values then u can create a temp table which has all the membership and personids

See If this code works for you:-

```
DECLARE @membership_id NUMERIC(9)
DECLARE @person_id NUMERIC(9)


if(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempids') is not null)      
drop table #tempids      

SELECT membership_id,person_id
into #tempids
FROM [dbo].[reb]
WHERE id_num <1160

while exists(select 1 from #tempids)
begin
-- select 1 row which will be called by proc

select top 1 @membership_id=membership_id
@person_id =person_id
from #tempids

EXEC p_get_details @membership_id, @person_id

--delete the ids which have been called by proc
delete from #tempids
where 
membership_id=@membership_id
person_id =@person_id


end
```