# How to Get multiple user update history in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please give some idea about how to get the users update history of particular id in SQL Server 2008.
I need to display their user names in (update) username column.

Example:

In database I have update username column in z table. The usernames are like shown here:

```
username
1.x
2.y
```

What I need is:

first x username  going to update some values for ID:1 in z table and save the details.
again y username also update some values for same ID  in z Table and save details.

In the end, I need an output that looks like this

`Z` table

```
    ID | column1| column2| update_username
     1 |    a   |  b     |    x,y
```

Comment: didnt understand what you want !! please provide sample input table schema and desired query output

Comment: Are you asking how to capture this information? SQL Server doesn't capture it by default.

Comment: Thanks for reply me.... what i am showing in output is possible to get that in sql

Comment: See SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to ge the expected result in `MSSQL server`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Z
(
 ID INT,
 Name VARCHAR(50)
 )

 INSERT INTO #Z 
 SELECT 1, '1.x' UNION
 SELECT 1, '2.y' UNION
 SELECt 2, '1.x' UNION
 SELECT 2, '2.y'

  SELECT A.ID,  Update_username = STUFF(
    (SELECT ', ' + SUBSTRING(B.Name, CHARINDEX('.', B.Name) + 1, LEN(B.Name))  
     FROM #Z AS B 
     WHERE B.ID = A.ID 
     GROUP BY B.Name 
     FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1,2,'') 
 FROM #Z AS A
 GROUP BY A.ID
```