# SQL row values to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which return the below data;

[image]

I need to write Values to one row depend `ID` and `Code` column like below;

[image]

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: [COALESCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700961/using-coalesce-function-to-make-values-separated-with-commas) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ID, Code, STRING_AGG(Value) AS Value
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY ID, Code;
```

Considering you're using up to date version.

Comment: Thats solve it i think. First attempt is succesfull. Thank you.

Comment: If this all works - please accept this answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below attempt. There are other options also you can use.

```
 SELECT
    CAST(408 AS INT) AS ID,
    CAST(1 AS INT) AS CODE,
    CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(20)) AS VALUE
    INTO 
    #tmpgroupby
    
    INSERT INTO #tmpgroupby
    VALUES 
    (408,1,'B'),
    (408,1,'C'),
    (408,1,'D'),
    (408,1,'E'),
    (408,1,'F'),
    (408,1,'G'),
    (408,2,'H'),
    (408,2,'I'),
    (408,2,'J'),
    (408,2,'K')
    
    SELECT ID,CODE, STUFF(
             (SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.VALUE, 120)
              FROM #tmpgroupby t2
              where t1.ID = t2.ID
              AND t1.code = t2.CODE
              FOR XML PATH (''))
              , 1, 1, '') 
               FROM #tmpgroupby t1
    GROUP BY ID,CODE

--- below also give the same result
  
SELECT ID, Code, STRING_AGG(VALUE,',') AS Value
FROM dbo.#tmpgroupby
GROUP BY ID, Code;

    DROP TABLE #tmpgroupby
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Sql Server:**

```
SELECT ID, CODE,
 Value=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + Value FROM table_name t1 
             WHERE t.Code =  t1.Code FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 

 FROM table_name AS t
 GROUP BY ID, Code
```